# RegEx to convert delimited ASCII number to characters

Tags: java, regex

I have data with parenthesized numbers embedded in them that I want to convert to character.  The numbers represent the ASCII decimal code of the character.  Is there a way to get a RegEx expression to convert the numbers to strings?

For instance:

```
(124)PEANUT(32)BUTTER(32)(43)(32)JELLY(32)(61)(32)NIRVAVA(124)
```

... should convert to ...

```
|PEANUT BUTTER + JELLY = NIRVANA|
```

I can't seem to come up with anything that works.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: No. Regex can *find* the codes, but not *convert* them.

Answer (score 0):

This works in JavaScript:

```
var input = '(124)PEANUT(32)BUTTER(32)(43)(32)JELLY(32)(61)(32)NIRVAVA(124)';

var output = input.replace(/\((\d+)\)/g, function(_, $1) {
  return String.fromCharCode(parseInt($1));
});
```

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method on strings can take a function as a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with .NET, the [`Regex.Replace()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably what you're looking for:

```
string inputString = "(124)PEANUT(32)BUTTER(32)(43)(32)JELLY(32)(61)(32)NIRVAVA(124)";
string pattern = @"\((\d+)\)";
string fixedString = Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern, delegate (Match m) {
    return ((char)Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value)).ToString();
});
```